# How to push View in Tabbar for android in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, reactive-programming

I have following code with Two tab, I have a View1.js page and View2.js page .I want to push these View1 and View2 in tab bar.

Here is my code.

```
import React, {
 AppRegistry,
Component,
 StyleSheet,
 Text,
 View,
 TextInput,
Image
} from 'react-native';

var Signin=require('../signin')
var Registration=require('../registration')
var View1=require('./view1')
var View2=require('./view2')
import localStyles from './styles.js'
import componentStyles from '../styles.js'
import TabNavigator from 'react-native-tab-navigator';
class Main extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   selectedTab: 'view1'
  };
}
render(){
const { selectedTab } = this.state;
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <TabNavigator>
  <TabNavigator.Item
    selected={this.state.selectedTab == 'view1'}
     title="SIGNIN"
     onPress={() => this.setState({selectedTab:'view1' })}>
     {View1}
   </TabNavigator.Item>
   <TabNavigator.Item
     selected={this.state.selectedTab =='view2'}
      title="registration"
      onPress={() => this.setState({selectedTab:'view2' })}>
      {View2}
    </TabNavigator.Item>

      </TabNavigator>
      </View>
     )
 }
```

}

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create(localStyles)
 export default Main
```

And my view1.js has following code:

```
import React, {
 AppRegistry,
 Component,
 Image,
 StyleSheet,
 Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

 import localStyles from './styles.js'
import componentStyles from '../styles.js'

 var view1 = React.createClass({
  render(){
  return (


    <View>
    <Text> tab1</Text>
    </View>


     )
  },
 })

  const styles = StyleSheet.create(localStyles)


 export default view1
```

And my view2.js has following code:

```
import React, {
 AppRegistry,
 Component,
 Image,
 StyleSheet,
 Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

 import localStyles from './styles.js'
import componentStyles from '../styles.js'

 var view2 = React.createClass({
  render(){
  return (


    <View>
    <Text> tab2</Text>
    </View>


     )
  },
 })

  const styles = StyleSheet.create(localStyles)


 export default view2
```

Answer (score 0):

This example is a copy/paste of example taken directly from the [react-native-tab-navigtor](https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-tab-navigator) github.

You'd need to replace the `{homeView}` and `{profileView}` with your signup and register views.

```
<TabNavigator>
  <TabNavigator.Item
    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'home'}
    title="Home"
    renderIcon={() => <Image source={...} />}
    renderSelectedIcon={() => <Image source={...} />}
    badgeText="1"
    onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: 'home' })}>
    {homeView}
  </TabNavigator.Item>
  <TabNavigator.Item
    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'profile'}
    title="Profile"
    renderIcon={() => <Image source={...} />}
    renderSelectedIcon={() => <Image source={...} />}
    renderBadge={() => <CustomBadgeView />}
    onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: 'profile' })}>
    {profileView}
  </TabNavigator.Item>
</TabNavigator>
```

Comment: I tried this but i am getting error only child must be passed a children with exactly one chile..

Comment: Each render function can only return a single element. Double check yours because it sounds like you're returning more than one

Comment: <TabNavigator>
      <TabNavigator.Item
        selected={this.state.selectedTab == 'view1'}
         title="SIGNIN"
         onPress={() => this.setState({selectedTab:'view1' })}>
         {View1}
       </TabNavigator.Item>
       <TabNavigator.Item
         selected={this.state.selectedTab =='view2'}
          title="registration"
          onPress={() => this.setState({selectedTab:'view2' })}>
          {View2}
        </TabNavigator.Item>

          </TabNavigator>   This is the code  .

Comment: Yes, but what does the view2 render function look like?

Comment: @sandy this looks fine to me. I tried creating an [example app on rnplay](https://rnplay.org/apps/m6nFOQ) but it doesn't run. When tried it locally, I get the same error you're speaking of. Thought it might be a bug, but I don't see any [issues listed against the repo](https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-tab-navigator/issues) that match. I suggest you file your own issue. Sorry, hope you find a solution.